# Identify a sci-fi movie about intelligent aliens who attack an outpost

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember watching a movie a while ago about "intelligent" dog like aliens with like a spike or weapons in their tail (like a chimera) who had their home planet colonized by humans.

The humans nearly wiped them out but a few survived and the humans set up a perimeter grid to keep them out - movie is about how the protagonist has his family (wife and child) killed by the alien/s when they attack whilst he is off world. They break through the defences and revenge for the attack on their species - rest of the story is about how the protagonist hunts down the alien that killed his family.

Really good sci-fi movie that makes you think about how the aliens felt while their world was being wiped out just to make room for the humans.

Anyone know the name of this movie?

A bit of a cross between pitch black and star ship trooper style - but it is **not** Starship Troopers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Outlander (2008) - Movie Poster]

[**Outlander** (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0462465/)

> In 709 AD, in the Iron Age, a spacecraft crashes in the Viking kingdom
>   of Herot, Norway, and the pilot Kainan survives. He turns the beacon
>   on; learns the language and culture of the planet using a machine; and
>   finds that the predator, Moorwen, that he was transporting, had
>   escaped. While chasing the alien monster, he finds a village
>   completely destroyed and is arrested by the warrior Wulfric, believing
>   that he killed the locals - Kainan is brought to Herot as a prisoner.

From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlander_%28film%29) page, the details you mentioned:

> Kainan's people came to the Moorwens' world to establish a colony,
>   killing the natives and claiming the planet for themselves. As a
>   reward, Kainan's wife and son were given a home in the new colony,
>   while Kainan and the armed forces left for other conquests. Later, one
>   surviving Moorwen slaughters all the colonists, including Kainan's
>   family. Kainan was dispatched to capture the beast and was returning
>   with it to his homeworld when it broke free and caused the crash.

[image: Outlander (2008) - Pic 01]
[image: Outlander (2008) - Pic 02]

Most of what you've described takes place in flashbacks, but otherwise it's a perfect fit.

You can browse through many more screenshots [here](http://www.cinemasquid.com/blu-ray/movies/screenshots/sets/outlander/9f1fefb8-6203-419a-ae85-23837a5e2546#screenshots).

Read more about the movie [here](http://scifimusings.blogspot.in/2010/07/outlander.html), [here](http://www.beyondhollywood.com/outlander-2008-movie-review/), [here](http://www.examiner.com/review/dvd-review-outlander-2008-an-imaginative-intersection-of-sci-fi-and-history) and [here](http://io9.com/5135803/the-saga-behind-viking-alien-war-movie-outlander). Watch the trailer [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZBoXCLG_28) or [here](http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi3628270361/).

Comment: Glad to help. Whenever you're back, do remember to 'select' this answer; read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) page for instructions. Happy viewing and enjoy your weekend!

Comment: ok - have selected your answer - many thanks again!

Comment: "It destroyed his world" The catchline leaves out the part where he destroyed its world first.